# How to use an object's instance variables in const_missing(), threadsafe?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to treat certain uppercase identifiers as dynamically calculated constants - so when I evaluate a code string such as eval("foo(BAR)") I can look up the value of BAR and supply it to the evaluation.

Don't even ask why I want to do this. :-)

The trouble is that const_missing() (unlike, say, method_missing() ) must be a class method, not an instance method. So if I try to write a function like this:

```
  def self.const_missing(name)
    if @data[name]
      return @data[name]
    end
    raise "Missing const #{name.inspect}"
  end
```

I can't see the instance variable @data that tells me what the value of FOO should be.

I could of course use a class variable @@data, but that would not let me a different data for each object. I could set @@data from @data immediately before doing the eval, but that would not be thread-safe nor recursion-friendly.

My fallback is to use thread-local storage to contain a stack of @data, and push and pop @data before and after the eval call. But that feels so... inelegant.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Don't even ask why I want to do this. :-)

thx for the suggestion, but why exactly are you doing this?

i'm asking because there probably is a different approach that people can show you if you try to explain the problem you are trying to solve.

another thing, don't ever use `eval`. just don't! if you are not able to one of the other possible metaprogramming methods like `class_eval` `instance_eval` `method_missing` and friends, you are probably doing it wrong.

let me emphasize, DONT USE `eval()`!

Comment: I could just as easily use self.instance_eval("foo(BAR)"). The string comes from a data structure produced by a GUI used by in-house programmers to add code snippets to be executed on certain conditions... the code also has to be available as strings... In theory I could downcase BAR to bar before execution and use method_missing, but that would add other complications.